# ¿Cuál es la palabra para algo que no se sabe cómo decir?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

En inglés para referirse a algo que no tiene nombre o que no se sabe cómo decirlo, tenemos varias palabras:

- **thing** --> *What is that **thing** on the wall?*
- **thingy** --> *How does this **thingy** work?*
- **thingamajig** --> *Please give me that **thingamajig** over there.*
- **whatchamacallit** --> *Then the, uh, **whatchamacallit** broke and I couldn't use it anymore.*
- **doohickey** --> *First, you fasten this **doohickey** to the frame...*

¿Hay algunas palabras así en español?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hay frases como *lo que sea/fuera/fuese/fuere* o *no sé qué no sé cuánto*, *cómo se dice/cómo se llama*.  A veces estas se escriben escritas, sobre todo cuando se sustantivan, en una palabra, a pesar de la [recomendación](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/no-se-que-noseque/) de Fondéu: un *[nosequé](https://books.google.com/books?id=cEHWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22nosequ%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7-vyOpMPUAhXIWSYKHZNLCJMQ6AEIZzAI#v=onepage&q=%22nosequ%C3%A9%22&f=false)*, un tal *[cómosellama](https://books.google.com/books?id=K2P_maeJYzYC&pg=PA39&dq=%22comosellama%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT6MjipMPUAhUK7SYKHb6VCy0Q6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22comosellama%22&f=false)*, etc.

Pero quizás lo más común —y, de hecho, panhispánico— sería *cosa* y sus diminutivos como *cosita/cosiña/cosilla* etc según región, sobre todo con demostrativo.

Para variantes con límite geográfico, tenemos:

- *chisme* (España y Méjico, quizás otros)
- *artilugio* (España)
- *cacharro* (España)
- *chunche* (Méjico y Centroamérica)
- *vaina* (Colombia y Caribe, quizás Centroamérica)
- *coso* (Colombia, Argentina, y otros)
- *pituto* (Argentina y Chile)
- *chirimbolo* (Argentina)
- *cusifai* (Argentina)
- *huarifaifa* (Chile)
- *pendorcho* (Argentina)

Todos estos términos, igual con *cosa*, se usan con frecuencia con algún demostrativo antes o después, o en forma diminutiva: *el coso ese*, *la cosa aquella*, *la vainita*, *ese chirimbolo*.

Comment: Te pasa como a mí, "guifa", que erras tipográficamente, aunque no ortográficamente. Artifulio ha de ser, creo, de no ser una palabra que aún no conozco; más bien artilugio.

Comment: _chirimbolo_ también lo he oído en España. _artilufio_ nunca (ni tampoco _artilugio_, si es en este contexto). _vaina_ lo oí en Colombia con frecuencia. Añadiría tal vez _cosilla_, usado en España con frecuencia.

Comment: @user55514 así es. Ya corregido, gracias

Comment: Estas palabras son comodines. No sirven solo para designar lo que no tiene nombre o no sabemos cómo se llama, sino para no hacer el esfuerzo mental de encontrar una mejor palabra. Y creo que éste es el uso principal y la razón de su frecuencia. Para el caso de Chile hay que agregar estas dos: _cuestión_ y _güevá_.

Comment: En Perú no se dice "coso". Se dice "cosa". Pero tenemos expresiones como "¿Cómo se llama esa vaina?" o "¿Queesa vaina?" puedes agregar al final "brother" o "causa"que es como decir "dude" o también se dice "Puta ¿Cómo se llama esa huevada?" o "Pucha ¿Cómo se llama esa wada?" o "ucha ¿cómo se llama esa waa?" o aún "cha ¿y esa wa'a?". Para todo es "vaina" (thing) en la capital en vez de cosa. Pero es un lenguaje de barrio y popular, considerado por muchos como vulgar. Hablado entre amigos muy cercanos y de ésta nueva generación

Comment: Un [ejemplo gráfico](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7223/7281032602_f9072a5c27.jpg) que ya pulula en las ferreterías argentinas.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Cuando cambias lo que ha escrito alguien, por favor solo hazlo en el caso de existir algún error.  Literalmente dije yo «a veces escritas en una palabra» y pusiste espacios en los ejemplos que di..  *Méjico* y *México* se acepta para escribir el nombre del país.  Soy de ascendencia neomejicana (alburquerqueña, específicamente) y así lo escribo yo siempre.

Comment: En referencia a cierto tipo de objetos pequeños para Argentina vale también *pendorcho*.

Comment: @pablodf76 gracias, ya añadido

Comment: guifa, ¿cuando tengas tiempo, podrías incorporar las aportaciones de los comentarios?  Nota que en Venezuela también se usa *vaina*.

Comment: ¿Vale la pena crear enlaces a algún diccionario en cada caso, como [cacharro](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacharro) o bien [cacharro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6W3NjZG)?

Answer (score 4):

A mi aparte de los descritos por guifa [en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15027/5481) se me ocurren `movida` e `historia` como comodines para una situación que no sabes cómo describir.

> Cómo te ha ido con la movida/historia esa que tenías en el trabajo.

Recuerdo en una clase de bachillerato estar mirando células en el microscopio y un compañero preguntó si esas "movidas" estaban vivas o muertas, aunque ese tipo de uso es mucho menos frecuente que para referirse a "asunto" (especialmente problemático).

`whachamacallit` podría traducirse como "comosellame", "comosediga` o similar (quizás incluso un "loquesea").

> Pásame el *como-se-llame* ese de ahí.

Answer (score 4):

Te digo como traduciría **yo** las frases que das de ejemplo:

- *What is that thing on the wall?*: ¿Qué es **eso/la cosa esa** de la pared?
- *How does this thingy work?*: ¿Cómo funciona este **trasto**?
- *Please give me that thingamajig over there*: Por favor, pásame el **chisme** ese de ahí.
- *Then the, uh, whatchamacallit broke and I couldn't use it anymore*:
  Luego el... eh... **cachivache** se rompió y desde entonces no he
  podido usarlo.
- *First, you fasten this    doohickey to the frame...*: Primero fijas
  este **chirimbolo** al    armazón...

Añadiré una variante de mi Córdoba natal: el *dese*, la *desa*, un *deso*... Lo curioso es que haya *dese* y *desa*. Se usan, más que cuando no sabes el nombre de algo, cuando no lo recuerdas (no te sale) pero *te parece recordar* el género de la palabra.

- Pásame el *dese*.
- Se ha roto la *desa* de la puerta.

Comment: ¿De qué país eres?

Comment: España. Es cierto que hay bastantes córdobas a lo largo de América también.

Answer (score 3):

En Bogotá, Colombia, se usan las siguientes palabras:

> Coso/a

Denota un objeto material cuyo nombre no se conoce. Por ejemplo *Alcánzame ese coso*.

> Cochornie

Igualmente para referirse a algo material pero con énfasis en algún dispositivo. Muy bogotano y antiguo.

> Aparato

Igual que *Device* en Inglés, es cualquier dispositivo mecánico, eléctrico, electrónico cuyo nombre no recordamos o conocemos.

Answer (score 1):

En México: (esto, eso, aqullo, esta cosa, esa cosa).

Las palabras "esto, eso, aquello" tienen un "objeto" sin nombre implícito, 
mientras que usar la palabra "cosa" da a entender que no se sabe el nombre del objeto, pero es un objeto de lo que se habla. (Se infiere que no es una persona).

thing --> What is that thing on the wall?

> Que es esa **cosa** en la pared? / Que es **eso** en la pared?

thingy --> How does this thingy work?

> Como funciona **esto**? / Como funciona esta **cosa**?

thingamajig --> Please give me that thingamajig over there.

> Por favor dame esa **cosa** de ahí / Por favor pasame **eso** de ahí

whatchamacallit --> Then the, uh, whatchamacallit broke and I couldn't use it anymore.

> Y luego, **eso** se rompió y no lo pude usar / Y luego, esa **cosa** se rompió y no la pude usar.

doohickey --> First, you fasten this doohickey to the frame...

> Primero ajustas **esto** al marco / Primero ajustas esta **cosa** al marco.

Comment: Mmm. Creo que no has terminado de entender la pregunta (o yo no la he entendido bien). Creo que el OP no busca exactamente pronombres (que valdrían técnicamente para referirte a algo para lo que no sabes el nombre). En vista a los ejemplos dados en la pregunta busca un término tipo slang o menos convencional. No quiere tanto una traducción para "thing" como para "thingy". Tu respuesta es por otro lado "técnicamente" valida...

Comment: @Diego tienes razon. Las palabras son 'nonsense words'. Hay otras: whatsitsface, howsyourfather. whosit, ....