# "Thingy" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, coloquialismos

If I don't know the word in English when I'm talking, I'll say "thingy/thing" - until someone corrects me or I settle with a better word.

Ex:

> Use that **thingy** over there to make it work. Uhh...that thing, uh - the button? The port? Whatever it's called. Yeah, that thing.

I have heard from a Venezuelan that they use "vaina". "¿Qué es la vaina...?"

Is there a word like thing/thing in Spanish that is recognized in both Spain and most of Latin America? Something that I can use to keep the convo going in a more native way while not knowing the right word like I do in English? Is it just ***cosa***?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello indikoro and welcome to [spanish.se]! This is a good question, post, er... whatever, a good thingy :) Note that something quite related was asked a while ago: [¿Cuál es la palabra para algo que no se sabe cómo decir?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15026/1674). Take a look at it and, if it helps, let us know so we can link this question to that one (mark as duplicate). By the way, in the responses there I cannot find a generic one, this seems to be very area-dependent.

Comment: "cosita" me suena bien aquí.

Comment: It's not that easy. `Thing` is more integral in the english language (some-thing; any-thing; is that a thing now?;....), and usage as an interjection as you describe is def. frowned upon and does not convey clarity. For the diminutives and the problems entailed therewith, have a look here: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutivo  . Other than that cosilla or cosita will be understood by many.