# Spanish for "widget"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, informática

In computer science we are more or less used to the term *[widget](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/widget)*:

> An application, or a component of an interface, that enables a user to perform a function or access a service.

The user interface for the Stack Exchange sites hosts several of these widgets. The word is being used as is in Spanish, as the Spanish entry for the word is found [untranslated](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget) in the Wikipedia. Nonetheless, it offers an alternative in Spanish: *artilugio*, which is the translation for *gadget*, and is [defined](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3rqbNUf) as "mechanism, artifact" among other meanings.

Is there a better word in Spanish to convey what a *widget* is?

Comment: The term *widget* is a contraction of "window" and "gadget". The term *gadget* refers to an UI element that is visible to the user (so all widgets are gadgets), but widgets manage their appearance and behavior independent of the application (i.e. they contain code that filters, forwards and generates events, not just data). So this is an implementation detail that is relevant only to developers and UI designers, and everyone else is using these terms interchangeably anyway. If that distinction is important, a good translation would probably highlight it as well.

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd use "cachirulo".

Comment: Actually, according to m-w.com, the word "widget" was used as early as 1924, so I don't think it derived from "window" and "gadget". It has a long history before being used as a computer UI term.

Comment: I first encountered the word 'widget' in an economics class in the 1950s. It meant 'an unspecified manufactured object.'

Comment: También en [linguee.es](https://www.linguee.es) aparece muchas veces sin traducir: https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=auto&query=widget

Answer (score 11):

Cuando no quiero usar *widget*, la palabra que uso es **componente**:

> [**componente**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=A27vPdJ)
>
> 1. adj. Que compone o entra en la composición de un todo.

El contexto se encarga de dejar claro que me refiero a un componente visual:

> Tras evaluar la librería Javascript para la galería de imágenes, he creado un **componente** GWT para que podáis incluirla en las pantallas que queráis sin necesidad de implementar lógica adicional.

No quiero imaginar la cara que habrían puesto mis compañeros si en vez de componente hubiese usado "adminículo" — por correcta que sea :D

Comment: Desde luego, "adminículo" suena demasiado culto, pero es que he visto la palabra hoy en Twitter y me ha molado y no he querido perder la ocasión para registrarla en el sitio. Por supuesto, esperaba más respuestas, así que gracias por animarte. :-) Eso sí, tengo entendido que "adminículo" se usa con cierta frecuencia en Hispanoamérica.

Comment: Soy fan de adminículo.

Comment: Componente, o en todo caso, "componente visual" para indicar que se refiere a algo que añade o se quita de un intefaz. "adminículo" no se usa en el español de España en la actualidad. Hacía años que no oía esa palabra.

Comment: Hispanoamericanamente hablando se usa más `componente` que `adminículo`

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is:

> **[adminículo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0m9nDrh)**
>
> Del lat. *adminicŭlum*.
>
> 1. m. Aquello que sirve de ayuda o auxilio para una cosa o intento.

In English:

> Something that serves as help or assistance for a thing or attempt.

Comment: mola la palabreja pero te reto a usarla en un proyecto serio de tu trabajo a ver que pasa, en plan: _« ... y en el lateral de la página web pondremos un **adminículo** con la predicción metereológica.»_

Comment: @blonfu pues seguramente me mirarán muy raro, pero yo les miraré muy serio y les diré lo mismo que cuando en la peli de Vaiana (o Moana según el sitio) va Tamatoa, pronuncia la palabra "[decapod](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decapod)", mira al público y dice "look it up!". Pues eso, que la busquen en el diccionario. :-D

Comment: La verdad es que es la palabra que tiene la definición que mejor encaja pero se me hace muy rara y graciosa.

Comment: @blonfu jejejeje, ha dicho "culo"...

Comment: Otras opciones podrían ser **complemento** o **utensilio**, como sinónimos de uso más común que adminículo

Comment: @PabloLozano pues anímate y ponlo como respuesta. Cuantas más mejor. :-)

Comment: Esta es la opción que más me gusta. Aunque veo dificil que se extienda su uso. Las otras opciones, componente y control, en este contexto tienen su equivalente más directo en inglés en component y control cuyo uso está tan extendido como widget.

Answer (score 7):

You may use "control" in some cases, in the senses 7 or 8 of what *Real Academia Española* says (strongly related to 5):

> [**control**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AeYZ09V) Del fr. contrôle.
>
> 1. m. Comprobación, inspección, fiscalización, intervención.
> 2. m. Dominio, mando, preponderancia.
> 3. m. Oficina, despacho, dependencia, etc., donde se controla.
> 4. m. puesto de control.
> 5. m. **Regulación, manual o automática, sobre un sistema.**
> 6. m. testigo (‖ muestra).
> 7. m. **Mando o dispositivo de regulación.**
> 8. m. **Tablero o panel donde se encuentran los mandos. U. m. en pl.**
> 9. m. Examen parcial para comprobar la marcha de los alumnos.

for example if you want to refer to sliders or other things that respond to user command.

In Argentina we tend to go with the english word (with spanglish accent, of course :P). Informally, I'd say "coso" or "cosito" (depending on the size of the widget, probably)

Comment: Leí "coso" y empezó a sonar el himno 

Comment: ¡Lo de _coso_ me gusta mucho! Se comentó en [¿Cuál es la palabra para algo que no se sabe cómo decir?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15026/1674), donde vimos que cada país tiene su... coso jeje. A todo esto, bienvenida Silvia. Te animo a registrate y a seguir colaborando con el sitio, hay multitud de preguntas por ejemplo de [tag:argentina].

Answer (score -1):

In Costa Rica they use “chunche” which means “thingamajig”. That will at least get you by, no?

EDIT:
(first, grassyass for the negative vote)
I got to thinking how I was introduced to the word in regards to manufacturing of any small device and came back and googled "the origin of the word widget".
noun INFORMAL
noun: widget; plural noun: widgets
a small gadget or mechanical device, especially one whose name is unknown or unspecified.
COMPUTING
an application, or a component of an interface, that enables a user to perform a function or access a service.
Origin
1930s: perhaps an alteration of gadget.
Translate widget to Spanish:
"widget"

Then, on down the page I found more verification that the word originated to describe a mechanical thingy, even though currently used as a term for a computer item (which I guess was the original question).

From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
Jump to navigationJump to search
    Look up widget in Wiktionary, the free dictionary.
The word widget is a placeholder name for an object or, more specifically, a mechanical or other manufactured device. It is an abstract unit of production.[1] The Oxford English Dictionary defines it as "An indefinite name for a gadget or mechanical contrivance, esp. a small manufactured item" and dates this use back to 1931. It states that the origin is "perhaps U.S." and for etymology suggests that it may be a variant of gadget.[2] However, the term also appears earlier in George S. Kaufman and Moss Hart's 1924 play Beggar on Horseback.[3]

General Motors Corporation sponsored a short film in 1939, "Round and Round", which features widgets throughout.[4][5]

When discussing a hypothetical situation, the term is used to represent any type of personal property, with the corresponding term Blackacre used to represent any type of real property. In such use, the widget or Blackacre has whatever characteristics are relevant to the scenario. So, if the object being discussed needs to be a liquid, then the widget is liquid. If it needs to be light, heavy, manufactured, naturally occurring or whatever, the widget has the necessary characteristics. In technology, the term has a variant, gigawidget, which is used to describe an object that is fictitious. The term is also used for obfuscation, if the object's real technology, composition, or purpose is unknown.[6]

Usage
"Widget" is used in texts and speech, especially in the context of accounting, to indicate a hypothetical "any-product". Companies in such texts will frequently be given names such as "ABC Widgets" or "Acme Widget Corp." to indicate that the particular business of the hypothetical company is not relevant to the topic of discussion.[7]

Comment: Welcome to [spanish.se]. We suggest you check the [tour] and [help] pages and have a look at other questions and answers to fully understand how this site works. Try your best to **really answer the question**, and remember that proper formatting can make your answer easier to read and understand. Keep in mind that your answer has to **explain** and provide some support or examples for what you are trying to get across. Do not hesitate to ask for help if you need it. Welcome again, and we hope to see more of your contributions!